# Angular acceleration of a double compound pendulum

Tags: kinematics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

How can I calculate the angular acceleration of a **double compound pendulum**? I'd like to know what the angular acceleration of each of the pendulum's center of mass will face at any point in time.

PS - Not a physics guy but love the subject would really like to learn. I'm programmer and I'm trying to simulate a double compound pendulum as an experiment.

Update - Got it. Found the equations here -> http://www.team.kdm.p.lodz.pl/master/Jankowski.pdf

Comment: Watch out, what are the units of $\mu$ in equations 4.5 and 4.6 in the linked document? There might be a typo there.

Answer (score 0):

The deflection angles of both pendulums are the degrees of freedom of the system.

First pendulum will have $\ddot{\theta}_1$ and second one will have $\ddot{\theta}_1+\ddot{\theta}_2$.

This is very trivial, maybe you are trying to ask something else?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to know how I can calculate the angular acceleration in terms of their masses, lengths, angles, etc at a given moment in time.

Comment: Well, you can find lot of examples from Google since it is the very basics of vibration and control studies. The equations of motion are readily available.

Comment: Thanks. Got the right calculations from here - http://www.team.kdm.p.lodz.pl/master/Jankowski.pdf